# XML data within tags

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and am new to XML. I have a query that generates output that looks like this:

```
<user id="12345">  --SAME USER ID
  <user_type>STUDENT</user_type>
  <name_first>Jane</name_first>
  <name_last>Smith</name_last>
  <email>jsmith@somedomain.com</email>
  <transcript>
    <course id="ACC101">
      <title>Accounting 101</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>B</grade>
    </course>
  </transcript>
</user>
<user id="12345">  --SAME USER ID
  <user_type>STUDENT</user_type>
  <name_first>Jane</name_first>
  <name_last>Smith</name_last>
  <email>jsmith@somedomain.com</email>
  <transcript>
    <course id="ENG151">
      <title>English 151</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>A</grade>
    </course>
  </transcript>
</user>
<user id="12345">  --SAME USER ID
  <user_type>STUDENT</user_type>
  <name_first>Jane</name_first>
  <name_last>Smith</name_last>
  <email>jsmith@somedomain.com</email>
  <transcript>
    <course id="MAT102">
      <title>Math 102</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>B</grade>
    </course>
  </transcript>
</user>
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
<user id="12345"> -- ALL DATA SHOULD BE WITHIN THE USER TAG
  <user_type>STUDENT</user_type>
  <name_first>Jane</name_first>
  <name_last>Smith</name_last>
  <email>jsmith@somedomain.com</email>
  <transcript> -- ALL COURSE DATA SHOULD BE WITHIN THE TRANSCRIPT TAG
    <course id="ABC123">
      <title>Accounting 101</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>B</grade>
    </course>
    <course id="ENG151">
      <title>English 151</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>A</grade>
    </course>
    <course id="MAT102">
      <title>Math 102</title>
      <credits>3.0000</credits>
      <grade>B</grade>
    </course>
  </transcript>
</user>
```

If there more information that I can provide, let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 User_Type, name_first, name_last
FROM Users
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('User'), ELEMENTS
```

Adding the User to `ROOT` places all other elements underneath it. Hope this helps!